# React: Is it possible to pass an event to an underlying iframe?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have a React component that renders a YouTube video inside an iframe. To make the UI look nicer, we would like to "mask" the video with an arc at the bottom, so it seems to have a slightly rounded border.

So I naively created a div containing the arc mask, and positioned it above the iframe's bottom, using `position:absolute`.

However, I noticed that any click events are now "catched" by this div and don't reach the underlying iframe anymore. In effect, this means that YouTube's UI elements, like the position bar, cannot be used anymore.

Is there a way to pass click (and touch) events through an React component to an underlying iframe? I even tried to manually add a regular HTML div to the DOM of the React container on `componentDidMount`, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none` to the underlaying div. [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-overlay-xs0ef)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ position: "relative", padding: 20, textAlign: 'center' }}>
        {/* OVERLAY */}
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            pointerEvents: "none",
            background: "red",
            opacity: 0.1
          }}
        />
        {/* ANYTHING BELOW */}
        <button
          style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 18, cursor: 'pointer', background: 'orange', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white' }}
        >CLICK ME EVEN IF I AM BELOW THE DIV</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I also want to capture event on overlaying div.

Comment: The question was about adding an absolutely positioned mask above the YouTube player with all buttons working. I've answered it. It'd be better if you create another question because what you need is a bit different & about forwarding events.